# Find a key that's not in a list of values in a dictionary Python? (beginner)

Tags: python, dictionary

So what I'm trying to do is if I have a dictionary that has lists as their values, I have to find and print the unique keys or unique values:
Example:

```
my_dict = {dog:[cat,rat,bird],cat:[dog,bird,rat],mouse:[fish,fly,horse]}
```

and what I want to find is

1. which key(s) don't exist as values and print them (this would result in mouse), and
2. which values don't exist as keys (this would result in fish, fly, horse, rat, bird)

and then store said result for each in a new list

What I was attempting looked something like:

```
new_list = []
for i in my_dict.keys():
   if i not in my_dict.values():
      new_list = my_dict.values(i)
```

or something along these lines

Comment: `Ive tried a number of things` Please include those things in the question.

Comment: Oh, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Are you sure your expected result as stated in point 2 is valid? Did you maybe shorten the example so it doesn't apply anymore? I see `rat, bird, fish, fly and horse` as values without corresponding keys. Also, are the keys and values supposed to be strings? In that case you should quote them.

Comment: Your code contains a bug in the last line. That is assigning a new list to the `new_list` variable every time, whereas you rather want to extend the existing one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you can flatten all of your values with [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> my_dict = {'dog':['cat','rat','bird'],'cat':['dog','bird','rat'],'mouse':['fish','fly','horse']}
>>> values = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(my_dict.values()))
>>> print(values)
['cat', 'rat', 'bird', 'dog', 'bird', 'rat', 'fish', 'fly', 'horse']
```

Or with other methods:

```
>>> values = [lst for item in my_dict.values() for lst in item]
>>> print(values)
['cat', 'rat', 'bird', 'dog', 'bird', 'rat', 'fish', 'fly', 'horse']
>>> values = sum(my_dict.values(), [])
>>> print(values)
['cat', 'rat', 'bird', 'dog', 'bird', 'rat', 'fish', 'fly', 'horse']
```

Then you can extract keys that don't exist as values, and values that dont exist as keys:

```
>>> only_keys = [key for key in my_dict if key not in values]
>>> print(only_keys)
['mouse']
>>> only_values = [value for value in values if value not in my_dict]
>>> print(list(set(only_values)))
>>> ['rat', 'bird', 'fish', 'fly', 'horse']
```

**Note:** You must apply a [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#func-set) onto `only_values`, since values can be duplicated in a dictionary, and keys cannot.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily and efficiently do it with sets:

```
>>> my_dict = {'dog': ['cat', 'rat', 'bird'], 'cat': ['dog', 'bird', 'rat'], 'mouse': ['fish', 'fly', 'horse']}
>>> values = {value for l in my_dict.values() for value in l}
>>> keys = set(my_dict)
>>> values - keys
set(['fly', 'horse', 'fish', 'rat', 'bird'])
>>> keys - values
set(['mouse'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Input data:

```
my_dict = {"dog":   ["cat","rat","bird"],
           "cat":   ["dog","bird","rat"],
           "mouse": ["fish","fly","horse"]}
```

Creating a set of all animals in keys:

```
animals_keys = set(my_dict.keys())
```

Creating a set of all animals in values:

```
animals_values = set()
for values in my_dict.values():
    animals_values.update(values)
```

Checking for animals in keys but not in values:

```
animal_keys - animal_values
```

> ['mouse']

The other way around, animals in values but not in keys:

```
animal_values - animal_keys
```

> ['fly', 'rat', 'fish', 'bird', 'horse']

---

This is Python 3.